# MS Access 2013 form - attachment field go to new record

Tags: forms, vba, sharepoint, ms-access-2013

I'm extremely new to MS access and was able to create an access form for a SharePoint linked access database. Most of the tutorials concluded at "how to add attachment field and connecting to column (control source). After doing all this, the current situation is that the access form is able to send attachment to the sharepoint form. however, when access form is opened again to reuse, the attachment field shows the previous record's attachment. 
I have tried:(`me.attachment = ""`, `me.attachment = null`, `me.attachment = nothing`) 
but none of it worked. Could anyone help me with this and let me know how to go to the new record? 
I'm a novice to access and my coding ability is derived from Excel VBA. Any help is greatly appreciated!! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the form to jump to the new record from inside the already open form (like having a "new" button, or just jumping to the new record on the form load) use something like this (on the right section, in your case it should be on Sub Form_Load):

```
DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, Me.Name, acNewRec
```

But if you want to open the form from another form (like a a button that opens another form in add mode) us this instead:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Form_Name_Here", , , , acFormAdd
```

You can also select the form to open in add mode in the form properties, if you want the form to always open like this.

Comment: can i add something like:
'code' Sub GoToNewRecord()
     DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
End Sub
'code'
and then call it from the button click? As I've only only one form and no sub forms.
Will it be ok to call this bit on form load?

Comment: Yeah, just add it on form load, or wherever you want to call it, and copy it like I wrote. Me.Name can be changed by a string with the form name (which is what Me.Name returns anyhow). You can also insert it in a "New" button inside the form, it'll work either way.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. Private sub doesn't get executed. it halts midway

Comment: Thanks for responding @CyberClaw. The code which you gave me, I used it in my existing code to clear the form. But it didn't clear the attachment field. 
Now, I've a new issue persisting. The new data that is submitted through form overwrites the existing data in the DB. However, when the data is submitted through sharepoint itself, it works fine.